# What is the best way for caching database query for the Service Object inside the iterations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I have a rails Service Object - CarChecker and model AvailableCar:

```
class CarChecker
  def car_is_available?(car)
    list_of_available_cars.include?(car)
  end

  def list_of_available_cars
    AvailableCar.all.map { ... }
  end
end
```

Then I check every car somewhere in controller

```
cars.each do |car|
  CarChecker.new().car_is_available?(car)
end
```

How can I avoid of sending request `AvailableCar.all` for every iteration and send it only once? What is the best way for caching such kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You often see methods assigning to instance variables for caching like this.

```
def list_of_available_cars
  @allcars ||= AvailableCar.all.map { ... }
end
```

The first time `list_of_available_cars` is called, `AvailableCars.all...` will be executed, and the result stored in an instance variable. Subsequent times, the stored value will be returned.

For it to work this way, you would need to be reusing the same instance of the service class.

```
checker = CarChecker.new
cars.each do |car|
  checker.car_is_available?(car)
end
```

If you must use a new instance of `CarChecker` each time, then you can use a class variable instead of an instance variable (i.e. use `@@` instead of `@`):

```
def list_of_available_cars
  @@allcars ||= AvailableCar.all.map { ... }
end
```

As long as your `AvailableCar.all.map { ... }` is always going to return the same result, that should be fine.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me because I use a little bit more complicated structure and I need to send an argument `car` to the `CarChecker.new(car)` constructor on every iteration